# Adding a contact via adb or monkeyrunner

Tags: android, android-contacts, monkeyrunner

Does anyone know if there is a way to add a contact via adb or monkeyrunner?

Using

```
device.shell("am start -a android.intent.action.ACTION_INSERT -t ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE -e ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME "+name+" ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE "+number)
```

does not work for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
device.shell("am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Donald Duck' -e phone 555-1234")
```

Comment: @dtmilano Thanks, it worked for me, too!But I have 2 similar questions: 1) how to delete a contact (just use `android.intent.action.DELETE`?)? 2) how to delete ALL Android contacts at once?

Comment: @dtmilano Found a way to delete all contacts: `adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.contacts`. But then Contacts Sync should be turned off (and I could not find a way to do that from command line).

Comment: A [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) script to disable Contacts Sync for an Account it would not be that difficult. Give it a try and create a new question if you find any problems.

Comment: So did you find a way to erase a specific contact?
Furthermore, is there a way to erase all contacts without having to restart? For my case, Contacts app always crashes after erasing until a restart has been done!

Comment: If you (reader) are looking for a way to "Add and Save a Contact" with adb and Android Intents - you need to know that there is no way to do it. This answer works, but it does what an Android Intent is suppose to do - it launches an App ("Phone") with a particular screen open ("Add a Contact") with some details already in place (name='Donald Duck', phone='555-1234'), but it leaves the rest to a user. And from there it depends on: the default app/OS version/manufacturer/etc. So, as a result - you can use adb and Intent to launch something, but you cannot use it to fully complete the action.